# Is there more efficient way to write this sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need to write one efficient query on the 2 tables below, with the conditions follow the tables:
First Table

```
CityCode    CustomerID  AccountID 
Paris       1           1
Roma        2           1
London      1           2
Paris       3           2
Roma        4           3
Berlin      5           4
```

Second Table

```
Credit_card_ind Credit  AccountID 
0               1000    1
1               5000    2
0               2300    3
1               30000   4
```

0 - doesn't have card
1 - has a card

In the query we need the following conditions:
1. all customers which their credit is above 5000
2. not showing accounts where one of their customers doesn't have credit card
3. all the accounts where their credit is below 30000
4. not showing accounts where one of their customers is from 'Roma'
5. showing accounts with more than 1 customers.

(*) - there might be no records return.

i wrote the query as follow and i wanted to confirm its the best way to do so, **where the intention is to reduce the number of times we approach the tables and doing Joins**:

```
Select  c.AccountID,
        c.CustomerID        
From    Customers as c 
Join    credit_cards as ca on c.AccountID = ca.AccountID
Where   ca.credit > 5000 And ca.credit < 30000
And     c.AccountID not in  (
                            Select  Distinct newTBL.AccountID
                            From    (
                                    Select  c1.CustomerID,
                                            c1.AccountID
                                    From    customers as c1
                                    Join    credit_cards as ca1 on c.AccountID = ca.AccountID
                                    Where   ca1.credit_card_ind = 0
                                    Or  c1.CityCode like ‘Roma’
                                    ) as newTBL
                            )
And    c.AccountID in ( 
                        Select  newCus.AccountID
                        From    (
                                Select  AccountID,
                                        Count(CustomerID) as [Num_of_Cus]
                                From customers
                                Group by AccountID
                                ) as newCus
                        Where newCus.[Num_of_Cus] > 1
                        )
```

Comment: Give the long query's output, that way others can see what you're trying to do, and how you're doing it, rather than just how you're doing it.

Comment: You haven't shown the city code and without wildcards you may as well use equality = 'Roma', for wildcard (and a slower lookup if not necessary) you want a perent LIKE 'Roma%'. better yet if the city Roma had an id, an integer matching query would be quicker still.

Comment: Which database? For instance `not in` is very efficient in Oracle but a performance killer in MySQL.

Comment: sql server (thx for the comment, didnt know that ... though the efficiency measured by logic query rather than syntax)
no integer code for citycode, its an text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can simplify your query by removing the nested subqueries:

```
Select  c.AccountID, c.CustomerID        
From    Customers c Join
        credit_cards ca
        on c.AccountID = ca.AccountID
Where   ca.credit > 5000 And ca.credit < 30000 And
        c.AccountID not in  (Select  c1.CustomerID
                             From customers c1 Join
                                  credit_cards ca1
                                  on c.AccountID = ca.AccountID
                             Where  ca1.credit_card_ind = 0 Or c1.CityCode like 'Roma'
                            ) And
        c.AccountID in (Select AccountID
                        From customers
                        Group by AccountID
                        Having Count(CustomerID) > 1
                       );
```

This may help.  You can also write this using window functions, which are probably more efficient.  I think the following query captures your original conditions:

```
select c.AccountID, c.CustomerID 
from (select c.*, count(*) over (partition by c.accountid) as cnt,
             max(case when c.CityCode like 'Roma' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_Roma
      from customers c
     ) c join
     credit cr
     on c.accountid = cr.accountid
where ca.credit > 5000 And ca.credit < 30000 and
      c.cnt > 0 and c.cnt_Roma = 0 and
      ca.credit_card_ind <> 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT cs.AccountID
FROM   customer cs
       JOIN credit cr
         ON cs.AccountID = cr.AccountID
WHERE  CityCode <> 'Roma'
       AND Credit_card_ind = 1
       AND Credit > 5000
       AND Credit < 30000
GROUP  BY cs.AccountID
HAVING Count(cs.CustomerID) > 1
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, though its not good because in a general case  the query would return a record of an account where 
1.credit value is answering the limits
2.one of two customers has a credit where the second customer doesn't.
3.and customer is not from 'Roma'